# Not able to verify requests made to WireMock Server: "No Requests Exactly Match"

Tags: java, wiremock

I'm trying to verify a request I made to the WireMock Server, but I'm getting an error saying the requests don't exactly match. The only bit that doesn't match is the "Content-Type: plain\text" bit.

Please see below my code:

```
public class WeatherApplicationTest {


    @Rule
    public  WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(8080);
  //  public   WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(8090); //No-args constructor will start on port 8080, no HTTPS



    @BeforeClass
    public  static void setUpClass() {
        //wireMockServer.start();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static  void tearDownClass() {
        //wireMockServer.stop();

    }


    @Test
    public void statusMessage() throws IOException{

                wireMockRule.start();


         stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/user/1"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
        .withStatus(200)
        .withStatusMessage("Everything is fine")
        .withHeader("Content-Type","text/plain")));

       HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpClient client2 = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:" + wireMockRule.port() + 
        "/user/1");
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

       HttpGet request2 = new HttpGet("http://localhost:" + wireMockRule.port() + 
        "/some/else");
       HttpResponse response2 = client2.execute(request2);

        assertThat(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), is(200));
        assertThat(response2.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), is(404));


        verify(getRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/user/1"))
        .withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("text/plain")));


        wireMockRule.stop();



}
}
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

> No requests exactly matched. Most similar request was:  expected:< GET
>   /user/1
>
> Content-Type: text/plain
>
> > but was:< GET /user/1

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Don't call `wireMockRule.start() or .stop()` that's done for you by the rule.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to verify that the *request* had a `Content-Type: text/plain` header, whereas you're sending that as a response header only.

Remove `.withHeader("Content-Type", equalTo("text/plain"))` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Set the header to both your HttpGet requests

```
 request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
```

and it should work fine